# Mern stack update user profile without Redux

Tags: javascript, mern

**Hello.
Please I really need help with MERN stack.
I need help with manipulating  the routes in the front end (react) such that a user can register, his/her information will be mapped to the front end and available for profile update.
Please ask me any question, incase you don't understand what I'm asking for.**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you provide code with more clear explantion, it will be better.
anyway, this may help you:
you can use contextAPI for smaller web appplication instead of Redux.
if you dont want to use none of them. then you can **localStorage** to store your user data
I hope my answer is helpfull.